# Starting new activity from thread

Tags: android, multithreading, listview

I am running a listView with choices and when the user clicks on the element in the listView they will redirected to a new activity and the current one will close. This code runs but skips about 100 frames each time it does so. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this and if I am doing this correctly. Thanks!

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    switch(position){
        case 0:
            // Sets listView element selected.
            selectListViewItemLeft(position);
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Home_Page.this, Home_Page.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }.start();
            break;
        case 1:

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: runOnUiThread is not required..

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, you don't need to start new activities inside a thread, you can just start a new Activity:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    switch(position){
        case 0:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Home_Page.this, Home_Page.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

            break;
        case 1:

            break;
    }
}
```